# HTTP POST from java arrives as GET at server

Tags: java, android, http, post, get

I have a server with a CGI which prints the REQUEST_METHOD to the syslog.
I have web pages which can GET and POST to that CGI and both methods print what I expect.
I have a java program which can GET to it.
But when I try to use POST in Java:

```
URL url = new URL("https://192.168.10.178/mycgi");
conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); // <- this bit!
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

The result is a GET with a content length of zero.
Obviously I've got a bunch more code that sets content types and dispositions and writes data into it, but with or without the rest of it I still end up with a GET request arriving at the server.

I've found this complained about here:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/1535571?start=0&tstart=0

where a number of people seem to have the same issue, but there is no answer, and here:

[Android HTTP POST request sent from application but server "sees" it as a GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470775/android-http-post-request-sent-from-application-but-server-sees-it-as-a-get-re)

Where the solution was to use the apache http client stuff, which I would prefer to avoid if possible, because it adds a bunch of dependencies to a project which shouldn't need them.

I'm at a bit of a loss to explain this one. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: repeating comment from deleted answer: the request takes the form `https://192.168.10.178/mycgi` and definitely does not contain ? or = characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your server is not responding with a 302/301 response to the final destination. This may force the client to resend the POST as a GET.

See [What is the correct behavior expected of an HTTP POST => 302 redirect to GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605915/what-is-the-correct-behavior-expected-of-an-http-post-302-redirect-to-get) for an explanation of the cause.

The 301/302 may just be due to a missing trailing slash in the URL. Check you server logs for 301/302 codes before the 200 code.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a trailing slash - I tried `https://192.168.10.178/mycgi/` and it had no effect.  However, you seem to be right about the 302/301, and `https://192.168.10.178/path/cgi-bin/mycgi` is working.  I would like to know why web browsers work but my java code doesn't, but this answers my question!  Thanks.